# Add column of values from one array to another

Tags: php, arrays, merge

Here is array #1

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [first] => LightSpeed
            [last] => Administrator
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [first] => Tyler
            [last] => Nichol
        )
```

Here is array #2

```
Array
(
    [I-10] => Array
        (
            [user] => 2
            [total] => 46.64
        )

    [I-11] => Array
        (
            [user] => 2
            [total] => -46.64
        )
```

I just want to add [total] => $value to the first array so it looks like.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [first] => LightSpeed
            [last] => Administrator
            [total] => 46.64
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [first] => Tyler
            [last] => Nichol
            [total] => -46.64
        )
```

Pretty sure it is array_push but not sure how to loop it. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: how do you know key **0** in array one will match key **I-10** in array 2 ?

Comment: Look into http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit low tech, but I'd just loop through your array and insert the total item. Assuming you're just matching to the second array on the position of the items in the arrays:

```
$vals = array_values($arr2);
foreach($arr1 as $i=>$item) {
    $arr1[$i]['total'] = $vals[$i]['total'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to loop all the time .. `array_merge` can do the trick

```
function superMerge($a, $b) {
    $a['total'] = $b['total'];
    return $a;
}

$array1 = array(0 => Array("first" => "LightSpeed","last" => "Administrator"),1 => Array("first" => "Tyler","last" => "Nichol"));
$array2 = array("I-10" => Array("user" => 2,"total" => 46.64),"I-11" => Array("user" => 2,"total" => - 46.64));

var_dump(array_map("superMerge", $array1, $array2));
```

Output

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'first' => string 'LightSpeed' (length=10)
      'last' => string 'Administrator' (length=13)
      'total' => float 46.64
  1 => 
    array
      'first' => string 'Tyler' (length=5)
      'last' => string 'Nichol' (length=6)
      'total' => float -46.64
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array is not well formatted so I have done that in my answer. You might want to update your question

```
<?php
$arr1 = Array
(
     Array
        (
            'first' => 'LightSpeed',
            'last' => 'Administrator'
        ),

     Array
        (
            'first' => 'Tyler',
            'last' => 'Nichol'
        )
);

$arr2 = Array
(
    'I-10' => Array
        (
            'user' => 2,
            'total' => 46.64
        ),

    'I-11' => Array
        (
            'user' => 2,
            'total' => -46.64
        )
);


$n = count($arr1);
$i = 0;
foreach($arr2 as $arr)
{
   $arr1[$i]['total'] = $arr['total'];
   $i++;
}

var_dump($arr1);
?>
```

Result of `var_dump`

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'first' => string 'LightSpeed' (length=10)
      'last' => string 'Administrator' (length=13)
      'total' => float 46.64
  1 => 
    array
      'first' => string 'Tyler' (length=5)
      'last' => string 'Nichol' (length=6)
      'total' => float -46.64
```