# Transforming array values in elements of a subarray using PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to merge two arrays in a way that values of first array are transformed in first elements of the subarray and values of the second array are transformed in second elements of the subarray. Here my example:

```
Array01
(
    [0] => 41558194
    [1] => 44677841
    [2] => 44503689
    [3] => 40651770
)

Array02
(
    [0] => 551
    [1] => 546
    [2] => 531
    [3] => 519
)

mergedArray
(
    [0] => Array([0] => 41558194 [1] => 551)
    [1] => Array([0] => 44677841 [1] => 546)
    [2] => Array([0] => 44503689 [1] => 531)
    [3] => Array([0] => 40651770 [1] => 519)
)
```

What is the most efficient way to do this?
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: If they are same size, you can use only one foreach to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a concise example using array_map:

```
function merge_arrays($a1, $a2) {
    return array($a1, $a2);
}

$result = array_map("merge_arrays", $arr, $arr2);
```

Answer (score 0):

An example with your values :

```
  $array1 = array(
        0 => 41558194,
        1 => 44677841,
        2 => 44503689,
        3 => 40651770
    );

    $array2 = array(
        0 => 551,
        1 => 546,
        2 => 531,
        3 => 519
    );


    $finalArray = array();

    foreach ($array1 as $key1 => $value1) {
        $finalArray[$key1] = array($value1, $array2[$key1]);
    }
```