# How to put other elements of two array beside similar ones in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I have two arrays like this:

```
$a1 = array(
    array('fisrtname' => 'john', 'lastname' => 'smith', 'c1' => 10),
    array('fisrtname' => 'jane', 'lastname' => 'smith', 'c1' => 20),
    ...
);

$a2 =  = array(
    array('fisrtname' => 'john', 'lastname' => 'smith', 'c2' => 40),
    array('fisrtname' => 'jane', 'lastname' => 'smith', 'c2' => 50),
    ...
);
```

I need to combine these two like this:

```
$a3 =  = array(
    array('fisrtname' => 'john', 'lastname' => 'smith', 'c1' => 10, 'c2' => 40),
    array('fisrtname' => 'jane', 'lastname' => 'smith', 'c1' => 20, 'c2' => 50),
    ...
);
```

How can I do it using PHP and less code?

Comment: @Rizier123: I don't want to put lines of simple codes to make it done. Actually I'm looking for using some ready functions together, but I'd no idea.

Comment: This question contains an insufficient  [mcve].  As a result, you have received answers which provide the desired result by happenstance.  A better sample set of data would clarify if the two arrays may have a different number of rows or if some rows from one array might not have a corresponding row in the opposite array or if the related rows do not share a first level index.  We are left to assume that `fisrtname` and `lastname` must be used to determine the relationship between arrays.

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Merge row data from multiple arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16541555/2943403)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you're looking for is probably just a single function call: [array_replace_recursive()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace-recursive.php)

```
$a1 = array(
    array('fisrtname' => 'john', 'lastname' => 'smith', 'c1' => 10),
    array('fisrtname' => 'jane', 'lastname' => 'smith', 'c1' => 20),
);

$a2 =  array(
    array('fisrtname' => 'john', 'lastname' => 'smith', 'c2' => 40),
    array('fisrtname' => 'jane', 'lastname' => 'smith', 'c2' => 50),
);

$result = array_replace_recursive($a1, $a2);
var_dump($result);
```

which gives:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["fisrtname"]=>
    string(4) "john"
    ["lastname"]=>
    string(5) "smith"
    ["c1"]=>
    int(10)
    ["c2"]=>
    int(40)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["fisrtname"]=>
    string(4) "jane"
    ["lastname"]=>
    string(5) "smith"
    ["c1"]=>
    int(20)
    ["c2"]=>
    int(50)
  }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify that your answer does not "put other elements of two array beside similar ones", but simply merges arrays based on their first level index.  Additionally, you may wish to vote to close as Unclear because of the low-quality task description and lackluster mcve.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) functions to accomplish this.

`$a3 = array_map("array_merge",$a1, $a2);`

Comment: Please clarify that your answer does not "put other elements of two array beside similar ones", but simply merges arrays based on their first level index.  Additionally, you may wish to vote to close as Unclear because of the low-quality task description and lackluster mcve.

Answer (score 0):

If the array a1 and a2 length is same, You can use code below:

```
<?php

$a1 = array(
    array('fisrtname' => 'john', 'lastname' => 'smith', 'c1' => 10),
    array('fisrtname' => 'jane', 'lastname' => 'smith', 'c1' => 20)
);

$a2 = array(
    array('fisrtname' => 'john', 'lastname' => 'smith', 'c2' => 40),
    array('fisrtname' => 'jane', 'lastname' => 'smith', 'c2' => 50)
);

for ($i=0; $i < count($a1); $i++) { 
    $a3[$i] = array_merge($a1[$i],$a2[$i]);
    $a3[$i] = array_unique($a3[$i]);
}

var_dump($a3);

?>
```

Comment: Please clarify that your answer does not "put other elements of two array beside similar ones", but simply merges arrays based on their first level index.  Additionally, you may wish to vote to close as Unclear because of the low-quality task description and lackluster mcve.