# Merge two multidimensional arrays, preserve numeric keys, and combine values inside array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, merge

I have two arrays and would like to combine / merge / put them together.

```
$arr1 = array(
    0 => array(1, 2),
    1 => array(5, 6)
);

$arr2 = array(
    0 => array(2, 3),
    1 => array(6, 7)
);    

come_together_right_now($arr1, $arr2); // the missing function?
```

and the result would be:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [0] => 1 
        [1] => 2 
        [2] => 3 
    )
    [1] => Array ( 
        [0] => 5 
        [1] => 6 
        [2] => 7 
    )
```

There are way too many array functions! `array_merge` and `array_combine` and the recursive alternatives seem to replace the values and they don't preserve numeric keys. How do I do this?

Comment: Related: [Merge two arrays containing objects and remove duplicate values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10572546/2943403)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that they will always have the same keys!

```
$result = array();

foreach($arr1 as $key=>$array) {
    $result[$key] = array_merge($array, $arr2[$key]);
}
```

Comment: due to the keys being numeric, duplicates are being created.  Is there an array_merge I can put inside the loop that will overwrite duplicates?  I edited my result set to show what I mean.

Comment: Try `array_unique(array_merge($array, $arr2[$key]));`

Comment: perfect for me - it keeps sub-arrays the way they are

Answer (score 2):

I might be late of answering this question but this might help you simply using `array_map`,`array_merge` and `array_unique` function like as

```
$result = array_map('array_unique',array_map('array_merge',$arr1,$arr2));
print_r($result);
```

**Output**

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [0] => 1 
        [1] => 2 
        [2] => 3 
    )
    [1] => Array ( 
        [0] => 5 
        [1] => 6 
        [2] => 7 
    )
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/441963)

Answer (score 0):

Synchronously iterate the arrays to access their rows.
Merge rows, remove duplicates, then re-index the elements.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/iJY2s))

```
var_export(
    array_map(
        fn(...$rows) => array_values(array_unique(array_merge(...$rows))),
        $arr1,
        $arr2
    )
);
```