# Merge rows of two arrays containing objects by first level index

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, object, merge

I am trying to merge the results of two CodeIgniter queries.  The trouble is that the two arrays contain rows of objects and `array_merge()` does not work on objects.  How can I merge the two object arrays.

Input:

```
$array1 = [
    (object) [
        'trainerid' => 1,
        'firstname' => 'abc',
        'location' => 'area',
        'photo' => 'abc.jpg',
        'role' => 'user',
        'city' => 'bangalore',
    ],
    (object) [
        'trainerid' => 2,
        'firstname' => 'abcd',
        'location' => 'area',
        'photo' => 'abcd.jpg',
        'role' => 'user',
        'city' => 'bangalore',
    ],
];

$array2 = [
    (object) [
        'rating' => 3.0000,
        'users' => 0,
        'review' => 0
    ],
    (object) [
        'rating' => 4.0000,
        'users' => 4,
        'review' => 5
    ]
];
```

Desired output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  (object) array(
     'trainerid' => 1,
     'firstname' => 'abc',
     'location' => 'area',
     'photo' => 'abc.jpg',
     'role' => 'user',
     'city' => 'bangalore',
     'rating' => 3.0,
     'users' => 0,
     'review' => 0,
  ),
  1 => 
  (object) array(
     'trainerid' => 2,
     'firstname' => 'abcd',
     'location' => 'area',
     'photo' => 'abcd.jpg',
     'role' => 'user',
     'city' => 'bangalore',
     'rating' => 4.0,
     'users' => 4,
     'review' => 5,
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You've made a relatively basic task much harder to do by using CodeIgniter's `->result()` instead of `->result_array()`.  If you had arrays of arrays, then you could just use `array_map('array_merge', $array1, $array2)`, but that will not work with your object arrays.

Instead, you'll need to call `get_object_vars()` on each object (and you are going to be iterating multiple objects inside the outer `array_map()`.

Essentially, this task is a matter of iterating both arrays simultaneously, casting each pair of objects to array type, then merging the arrays, then casting the merged array back to object type.

The following snippet is designed with the flexibility to process 2 or more object arrays.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Z7jff))

```
var_export(
    array_map(
        fn(...$objs) => (object) array_merge(...array_map('get_object_vars', $objs)),
        $array1,
        $array2
    )
);
```

The above can be written a little more concisely when only two object arrays are being merged. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/qTuO8))

```
var_export(
    array_map(
        fn($obj1, $obj2) => (object) array_merge((array) $obj1, (array) $obj2),
        $array1,
        $array2
    )
);
```

A classic nested foreach approach can be used to avoid casting and recasting data types while merging.  `array_merge()` and `array_merge_recursive()` cannot (currently) be used to merge objects together -- their properties must be individually defined in the receiving object. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/RGeR0))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array1 as $i => $obj1) {
    $result[$i] = $obj1;
    foreach ($array2[$i] as $k => $v) {
        $result[$i]->$k = $v;
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

Output from any of the above snippets:

```
array (
  0 => 
  (object) array(
     'trainerid' => 1,
     'firstname' => 'abc',
     'location' => 'area',
     'photo' => 'abc.jpg',
     'role' => 'user',
     'city' => 'bangalore',
     'rating' => 3.0,
     'users' => 0,
     'review' => 0,
  ),
  1 => 
  (object) array(
     'trainerid' => 2,
     'firstname' => 'abcd',
     'location' => 'area',
     'photo' => 'abcd.jpg',
     'role' => 'user',
     'city' => 'bangalore',
     'rating' => 4.0,
     'users' => 4,
     'review' => 5,
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `array_map` along with the `array_merge` like as

```
print_r(array_map('array_merge', $arr1, $arr2));
```

Comment: This answer is [provably incorrect](https://3v4l.org/bbkrC).